# MySQL dynamic search query procedure

Tags: mysql, procedure

The MySQL query should return

1) `TRUE` along with Comma(,) separated list of `STATION_NAME` from a table `STATION WHERE STATION_NAME` is `LIKE` the `INPUT` specified buy the user.

FOR Ex:

`INPUT = A, OUTPUT= (Agra,Ajmer,Amritsar,Ambala)`.

```
INPUT = AM, OUTPUT= (Amritsar, Ambala)
```

2) `FALSE`, when no such station exists

3) `ERROR`.

Detailed `PROCEDURE` will be appreciated, as I am new to MySQL.
Thanks in advance.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a procedure, just a select that returns one row on success or no rows on failure:

```
select group_concat(station_name) from station where station_name like ?
```

where ? is a placeholder for the user entered search.

[group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) is a mysql-specific feature.

If you *must* use a procedure, it would be something like this:

```
create procedure stationsearch (in likewhat varchar(255), out rslt text)
begin
    select group_concat(distinct station_name order by station_name) into rslt from station where station_name like likewhat;
end
```

Used like this:

```
call stationsearch('Am%',@rslt);
select @rslt;
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. group_concat is working, Keeping in mind performance and optimization, We need to write the Procedure in the backend(in MySQL). But in the MySQL proc place-holder ? is not working.

Comment: Err, a procedure will help with neither performance nor optimization.

Comment: SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(STATION_NAME) FROM STATION WHERE STATION_NAME LIKE ? ; is not working. I even declared an INPUT PARAMETER VAR of VARCHAR2 and tried this SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(STATION_NAME) FROM STATION WHERE STATION_NAME LIKE VAR; CALL PROC_NAME('Am'); but not getting the desired output..

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamic"?

Comment: Shouldn't that be 'Am%' (and at least varchar(3))?

Comment: call proc_name('AM%') is giving me the result as [,,]. By Dynamic I mean the STATION_NAME will be given in the query browser.. P.S that was VARCHAR(10).

Comment: I've never used the query browser, so I don't know quite what that means :)

Comment: Hey thanks buddy, the code you gave worked.. Had some syntax issues...Anyway thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT station_name
FROM station
WHERE SUBSTRING(station_name, 1, LENGTH( ? )) = ?;
```